# Simple function to check if an array is consecutive

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple function that will test if a an array is consecutive but for some reason it does not work. This is a small part of an angular JS app if that's relevant.

```
        return function isConsecArray(arr){
          var i;
          var y = (arr.length);       
         for (i=0; i < y; i += 1){
         if (parseInt(arr[i])+1 !== parseInt(arr[i+1]))
         {
         return false;
         }

         }
         return true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reaching the last element, i.e. `i=y-1`, it compares `arr[i]` with `arr[i+1]`, which is undefined. You need to iterate up to `arr.length-1`, i.e.:

```
...
for (i=1; i < y-1; i += 1) { / NOTE THE y-1 LIMIT
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this:

```
function isConsecArray(arr) {
    var previous = arr[0];
    var i;
    var y = (arr.length);
    if (y > 1) {
        for (i=1; i < y; i += 1) {
            if (parseInt(arr[i]) -1  !== parseInt(previous)) {
                return false;
            }
            previous = arr[i];        
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dq1kccvk/